# Wrong page scroll response

Tags: html, css

For some reason I have the lower content of my page moving up and covering the "cover photo". Why is it doing that? What am I doing wrong?

Here is my source:

http://jsfiddle.net/JffAm/

Comment: You're nothing doing wrong, it's nice effect and i like it :) But if you don't want to have that effect, just remove "fixed" attribute. See answer below. For more informations "what's wrong", here is link about positioning in CSS http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 2):

It's because your image is fixed, which makes it stuck on the same position even if you scroll.